# CSSearchableAttributeset supportPhoneCall, Navigation are not working

Tags: ios, swift, spotlight, corespotlight

I'm trying to expose my app on Spotlight

Basic Info is now exposed but phone call and navigation are not working

This is my code below

```
    var searchableItems = [CSSearchableItem]()

    let hospitals = contents.compactMap { $0 as? Hospital }
    for hospital in hospitals {
        let searchItemAttributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeData as String)
        searchItemAttributeSet.title = hospital.name
        searchItemAttributeSet.contentDescription = "visited"
        searchItemAttributeSet.phoneNumbers = ["00-0000-0000"]
        searchItemAttributeSet.latitude = NSNumber(value: hospital.coordinate.latitude)
        searchItemAttributeSet.longitude = NSNumber(value: hospital.coordinate.longitude)
        searchItemAttributeSet.supportsPhoneCall = 1
        searchItemAttributeSet.supportsNavigation = 1
        let searchableItem = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "\(hospital.identifier)", domainIdentifier: "hospitals", attributeSet: searchItemAttributeSet)
        searchableItems.append(searchableItem)
    }

    CSSearchableIndex.default().indexSearchableItems(searchableItems) { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
        }
    }
```

While searching on Spotlight there are title and contentDescription but not phoneCall Button and navigation Button

How can I add them to result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the properties to `true`, not `1`

```
for hospital in hospitals {
    let searchItemAttributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeData as String)
    searchItemAttributeSet.title = hospital.name
    searchItemAttributeSet.contentDescription = "visited"
    searchItemAttributeSet.phoneNumbers = ["00-0000-0000"]
    searchItemAttributeSet.latitude = NSNumber(value: hospital.coordinate.latitude)
    searchItemAttributeSet.longitude = NSNumber(value: hospital.coordinate.longitude)
    searchItemAttributeSet.supportsPhoneCall = true
    searchItemAttributeSet.supportsNavigation = true
    let searchableItem = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "\(hospital.identifier)", domainIdentifier: "hospitals", attributeSet: searchItemAttributeSet)
    searchableItems.append(searchableItem)
}
```

Comment: thanks!! it works!! then why apple suggest NSNumber not Bool?

Comment: It is an NSNumber. An NSNumber can wrap a range of numeric types, including bool. Swift automatically wraps the numeric literal is an NSNumber

Comment: I have one more question, if I support only navigation, it works, but if I support both phone call and navigation, both icons are not visible what should I do?

Comment: From my testing it seems you can support one or the other, but not both, on a particular search result.

Comment: The constructor parameter `itemContentType: kUTTypeData as String` or  `contentType: UTType.data` is also very important. For example setting `itemContentType: kUTTypeContact as String` or  `contentType: UTType.contact` creates searchable item, only the dialing button is not shown. I wish it was written somewhere - now it is here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the keywords you want to search for.
for example searchItemAttributeSet.keywords = ["xxx", "xxx"];

Comment: not keywords I want to expose navigation and phone call button on spotlight result right side